# copy constructor failure... overloading, dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor, copy-constructor

I'm working with dynamic strings, and there is an issue with copy constructor and overloading.
I'm using an operator+ to overload. the overloaded function is used to interpolate two char * strings.
here's just an excerpt of the code:

```
  MyString::~MyString()
  {
    delete[] text; //char *text, as my private data
  }
MyString::MyString(const MyString & obj)//copy constructor here
{
    text = new char[obj.len];
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.len; i++)
    {
        text[i] = obj.text[i];
    }
    len = obj.len;
}
MyString MyString::operator+(MyString & s)
{
    MyString temp;
    temp.len = len + s.len + 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        temp.text[i] = this->text[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s.len; i++)
    {
        temp.text[i + len] = s.text[i];
    }
    temp.text[len + s.len] = 0;
    return temp;//PROBLEM HERE
}
```

and here's my problem:
the operator+ function calls both copy constructor and destructor before returning `temp`
and though there IS a copy constructor what is returned, is a deleted [] array.
what's the catch? Thanks

Comment: What does your default constructor do? Does `temp.text` have enough space allocated? Doesn't seem like it could.

Comment: it does have enough space.

Comment: Well if it does, that's an awfully strange implementation. You'd have to know the maximum possible size of the strings and allocate enough memory for that. Which doesn't sound very much like a dynamic string.

Comment: would you suggest me a more common implementation?

Comment: This code is schizophrenic. The copy ctor is implemented as if either `len` includes the terminating `'\0'` or that the string is not null-terminated, and then `operator+` is implemented as if `len` doesn't include a terminating `'\0'` and the string is null-terminated.

Comment: Also, please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for your compliment.and ill check that... @T.C

Comment: Well, you would check if your string had enough memory, and if it didn't, allocate more. I don't know how much memory you allocate in your default constructor, but you can bet that at some point you're going to want to add two strings together which will not fit in that.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the following code

```
MyString s1;  // Initialized to something
MyString s2;  // Initialized to something else

MyString s3 = s1 + s2;
```

Then the expression `s1 + s2` creates a *temporary* copy (the one returned by your `operator+` function). This temporary copy is then passed to the copy-constructor to create `s3` *followed* by the destruction of the temporary object.

That's the theory anyway, in reality the compiler will *elide* the copying.

Comment: well, i did so. but what is returned is not the interpolation of `s1+s2` its just a char * with value which seems like an address. like :0x0025ad10

Comment: @Potter6000 Make a small test-case (like the one in my answer), run in a debugger, set breakpoints in the copy-constructor and the destructor and the `operator+` function, and make sure the code behaves as expected by stepping through it line by line.

Answer (score -2):

Make these changes and try :
1. temp.text[len + s.len] = '\0';  //Null terminated

2. MyString**&** MyString::operator+(MyString & s)
   {
   .
   .
   .
   }
   //Return by reference, you will get the correct result.

Comment: No, you should not return a local object by reference.